# Does MongoItemWriter do a bulkops?

Tags: spring-batch

Does MongoItemWriter do a bulkops?
If not do i need to config something to make this bulk save?
This is my example code:

```
@Bean
    @StepScope
    public ClassifierCompositeItemWriter<PersIcon> compositeItemWriter(MongoItemWriter<PersIcon> writer,
                                                                       MongoItemWriter<PersIcon> deleter) {

        Classifier<PersIcon, ItemWriter<? super PersIcon>> classifier = (PersIcon entity) -> {
            if (StringUtils.hasText(entity.getServiceIds())) {
                return writer;
            } else {
                return deleter;
            }
        };

        ClassifierCompositeItemWriter<PersIcon> classifierWriter = new ClassifierCompositeItemWriter<>();
        classifierWriter.setClassifier(classifier);
        return classifierWriter;
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoItemWriter<PersIcon> writer(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
        return new MongoItemWriterBuilder<PersIcon>()
                .template(mongoTemplate)
                .collection("persIcon")
                .build();
    }
```

So does this code do the bulkops insert?

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my understanding, the `MongoItemWriter` performs bulk operations by default, and these operations are configured with `BulkMode.ORDERED`.

You can check out the code of the implementation here:
[GitHub - Spring Batch MongoItemWriter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/7fd34829f99f980c066d9b8e77d21e2efe97149e/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/item/data/MongoItemWriter.java#L200)

If you want to tweak this behavior to match your specific needs, you can create a custom MongoTemplate bean. Then, set it up with the settings you want to control how the bulk operations work.